# I2C support on non real time OS? How does it work?

Tags: i2c

I have my RPI3 (master) connected to an Arduino board (slave) via [I2C-bus](http://www.i2c-bus.org/). It works, except that after 5 seconds running communication over I2C I already get exceptions about 'No acknowledge from Slave'.

Since I never really understood how I2C (as some sort of [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation)) works on a non real time OS like Windows IoT, I thought lets start there. Find out *how* this works. But I can't find anything on that topic. Who can share me some more information on how this really works?

How does a non real time OS manages to support the I2C bus? What/Who is generating the SCL signal? What/who is reading the actual bytes on SDA? It can't be Windows IoT itself, so who is taking care of that? Why can I read bytes of the I2C bus? Who is buffering them for me? And how long are they buffered?

Really hope somebody who understands all this is willing to explain it.

Comment: `so who is taking care of that?`That'll be the I2C hardware in the chip.

Comment: Have you read UM10204 yet?

Comment: `as some sort of PWM`... I2C is PWM? And there was me thinking it was a synchronous serial bus with open drain interfaces...

Comment: *Since I never really understood how I2C (as some sort of PWM) works on a non real time OS like Windows IoT* 1) I2C has **nothing** to do with PWM. Maybe you meant SPI (Serial Bus Interface) ? 2) an OS is not even needed to "do" I2C. I2C is at a much lower level and designed for communications between ICs. Google "how does I2C work" and you will find plenty of explanations on how I2C works.

Comment: @Majenko, right, so a PWM is something completely different. Read a bit more and I guess that was a ridiculous assumption. Back to your first comment "That'll be the I2C hardware in the chip". So there is a dedicated I2C chip on my RPI? I think I understand the basics of how I2C communication works, generating a bit pattern, using the SCL clock line to create start and stop communication patterns. Does this chip also buffer the bytes I can read?

Comment: `So there is a dedicated I2C chip on my RPI?` No, there is a dedicated I2C circuit *inside the Broadcom SoC*. And the data is buffered both by the I2C hardware and the kernel. You send data to the kernel, the kernel feeds it to the I2C hardware, the I2C hardware generates the signals.

Comment: The I2C hardware is not a dedicated chip, it is **so simple** that even many microcontrollers have this build-in. The CPU on the RPi is so powerfull, it can do I2C with two fingers in it's nose.

Comment: @FakeMoustache, but if a non real time OS is running on the RPI, then even a trivial concept as I2C will become unstable, right? Shouldn't the OS at least be able to monitor the SDA/SCL within microseconds to read the bits?

Comment: The OS doesn't speak to the lines directly, any more than your PC OS speaks directly to the USB bus or the monitor. It's delegated to hardware.

Comment: Yes and that is why it is using dedicated hardware. So it works independently of the OS. The OS just reads/writes to the "I2C port"  and the I2C hardware does the rest. You should loose the idea that the I2C is run through software because **it is not**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing to do with PWM. There's hardware support for it on the chip. The OS doesn't have to generate the level changes itself, there will be a number of memory locations (often called registers, but these registers belong to the *peripheral* and are not to be confused with the processor's registers) which control it. The OS pre-loads them with speed and output values, then gets on with something else.

The peripheral generates its own timing, sends the output signal, reads a reply and puts it in a buffer. Then it sends an interrupt to the OS. The OS makes it available to user programs somehow (in Win10, this will be some sort of ReadFile interface?).

The only thing I don't know is how deep the buffer in the hardware is.

You may find it much easier to get things working with Linux on the Pi, as there's lots more documentation and you can have a look at the C source for the OS I2C drivers.

Comment: OK that is something that makes sense to me. So there some kind of a dedicated hardware infrastructure that allows a non real time OS to use an I2C bus? Right, just read your comment above. So would the same apply to Dallas OneWire? Or is there nothing in place on a RPI to support that protocol as well? (sorry for all the questions, I am relatively new in this overwhelming field of electronics, I am just trying and hoping to learn more)

Comment: Yes, it's a dedicated peripheral. There isn't a dedicated peripheral for OneWire, sadly. But people have written software drivers for it that work well enough: https://www.modmypi.com/blog/ds18b20-one-wire-digital-temperature-sensor-and-the-raspberry-pi (timing won't be perfect but is evidently "close enough")

Answer (score 1):

The clock in I2C is generated by the master, and can be arbitralily slow. Hence it can be genrated in software, even on a non-realtime OS.

But as Majenko commented, the Pi chip has hardware I2C support, so I assume the Linux driver uses this and let's that hardware generate the clock.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But shouldn't the clock signal at least be deterministic?

Comment: What do you mean by 'deterministic'? A fixed frequency? Nope, that is not required.

Comment: So is the clock generated by software or by hardware as pjc50 explains?

Comment: That depends on exactly what you do and the software involved. My best guess is that you somehow use the I2C driver that is part of the Linux kernel. I am not totally sure how that one works, but a good guess is that it uses the hardware I2C peripheral of the Broadcom chip. But it doens't have to, and your application could use bit-banged (software controlled) I2C without involving the Linux driver.

Comment: Hi Wouter, sorry for being absent, was celebrating the fact that I have my setup working stable :). +1 for the bit bang, was a good and interesting google as well! The good news for me: everything works, so we can move forward with our little project! :) Thx for helping/advising/educating!